# How to add Hardware and OS selections in Bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

When reporting a bug in Bugzilla you are presented with a drop-down selection for the Hardware platform and OS.  The options for Hardware are {All, PC, Mac, Other} and for OS they are {Win, Mac, Linux, Other}.  I'd like to add "VME" into the Hardware list and "VxWorks" in the OS list.  How do I do that?

Yes, I know those fall into the 'Other' category, but I'd rather it be explicit.

Sorry, it was there all along. Just needed to log in as the administrator, go to the Administration page (right side of menu bar), then select Field Values (right side of page).  That allows you to change the OS, and Hardware selections, along with other values.

Answer (score 4):

In Bugzilla 4.4.9 you go to Administration > Field Values where you edit Hardware, OS, Status, Resolution, Severity, and Priority field values.

Answer (score 3):

Okay. The new options in the drop down can be added from the database. There will be tables for each category of drop down. These select options are different custom fields. You can search the table cf_hardware or cf_Os in techzilla database.

insert into cf_hardware values('','',200);

Try this.